# Setting up clean database for each test when using postgresql

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to find a way to create set of tests that would need to have a clean database before running test case.

InMemoryDB seems not to be an option because the DDL we use fails to execute in H2.

The database creation is done with evolutions, so it would be handy if I was able to use evolutions to generate clean database for each test and then drop the database after test is run.

Marko

Answer (score 0):

As option you can try Flashback (or Point In Time Recovery) feature to restore DB initial state or consider writing of tests that does not depend on each other.